# Range Values for "Float" data type in C++

Tags: c++

I need to validate float data type Minimum and maximum value.

For Ex: unsigned __int8  is 0 to 255

Like this i need to expand Float min and max value.

float ----> 3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits) How to Expand this.

Comment: Do you mean you need to see every digit (as in take the float out of scientific notation)? Also choose a language. C and C++ will have different answers (as seen below).

Comment: Yes i need every digit of float minimum and maximum value -- C++

Comment: If it's C++, why did you tag the question C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "Because you get better answers if you tag more languages" - you should know that by now... ;) [Edited away the "C" tag]

Answer (score 7):

You just want to know the supported range?  You can use `numeric_limits` for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << "Float Range"
       << std::numeric_limits<float>::min() << " / "
       << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As discussed in the comments, `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` gives the smallest positive value for a `float`, while `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()` gives the largest possible negative value, and may be more appropriate.  `lowest()` however is `C++11` only.

Comment: Isn't the "minimum" value there the smallest positive value for floating point types? See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min for reference.

Comment: And if you want greater precision, it might be worthwhile looking at the `setprecision` expression in the [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) header